# Laravel: orderBy relationship's field

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an issue with ordering model by it's relationship's latest object field.

I have a class named Coin that is related to DailyPrices, that 1 coin can have many DailyPrices. I want to sort coins by latest DailyPrices field named `vol`.

I tried doing

`$coins = Coin::join('daily_prices', 'daily_prices.coin_id', '=', 'coins.id')
            ->orderBy('daily_prices.vol', 'desc')
            ->paginate(100);`

and many variations about it, but I can't get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you mean "latest field named vol"? Do you mean the highest value of `vol`? Or does "latest" refer to a date(time) column?

Comment: Every 15 minutes there's a new DailyPrice created for each coin. I want to get all latest DailyPrices for each coin and sort them by `vol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the question was unclear, I don't know. But neither of these were relevant to an issue. I have resolved the problem with this query:

```
SELECT c.* FROM daily_prices AS dp JOIN coins AS c ON dp.coin_id=c.id WHERE dp.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM daily_prices GROUP BY coin_id) ORDER BY vol DESC
```

and transformed to laravel call:

```
 Coin::join('daily_prices', 'daily_prices.coin_id', '=', 'coins.id')
                ->whereIn('daily_prices.id', function ($query) {
                    $query->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
                        ->from('daily_prices')
                        ->groupBy('coin_id');
                })
                ->orderBy('daily_prices.vol', 'desc')
                ->paginate(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use created_at instead of vol

```
$coins =  Coin::join('daily_prices', 'daily_prices.coin_id', '=', 'coins.id')->order_by('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [One to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) :

```
class Coin {

    public function dailyPrices() {
        return $this->hasMany(DailyPrice::class);
    }

}
```

DailyPrice :

```
class DailyPrice {

    public function coin() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Coin::class);
    }

}
```

Then in your controller :

```
Coin::with('dailyPrices' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('vol', 'desc');
))->paginate(100);
```

The with function will load dailyPrice relationship on your item and the value argument will execute a query related to the relation loaded (here an order by).

Hopes it helps you.

Comment: Could you please correct the controller part? That's not a valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can do with creating two separate model for coin and daily price.

```
class Coin extends Model {
    public function dailyPrices(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\DailyPrice')->orderBy('vol', 'DESC');
    }
}
class DailyPrice extends Model {

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'daily_prices';
    /**
     * Get the coin that owns the daily price.
     */
    public function coin()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Coin');
    }
}
```

and call with ID in your controller like this

```
$coinData = Coin::find($coin_id)->with('dailyPrices')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes in your code:

- Condition check
- Not select table

Here is a code after making changes:

```
$order='desc';
Coin::join('daily_prices', 'coins.id', '=', 'daily_prices.coin_id')->orderBy('daily_prices.vol', $order)->select('coins.*')->paginate(100);
```

You can also see more details from here:[Order by on relationship](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/order-by-on-relationship)